# В чем ошибка (js) ? N=NaN

Tags: javascript

```js
A = [
  [1, 20],
  [4, 10],
  [9, 3]
];
x = [7, 1, 6];
y = [0.3, 0.4];

var ay = [];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    ay[i] += A[i] * y[j];
  }

sk = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
  v[i] += ay[i] * x[i];
  sk += v[i];
}

n1 = sk * m * n;
console.log('N=', n1);
```

Comment: `n is not defined` и m

Comment: n is not defined

Comment: Судя по всему, это не весь код. Добавьте, пожалуйста, целиком.